# Error while applying configuration using PowerShell DSC VM extension : "Compilation errors occurred while processing configuration"

Tags: azure, powershell, dsc

I have a simple configuration that I am trying to apply to an Azure VM using PowerShell DSC extension

```
Configuration DSCTest
{
    Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName xPSDesiredStateConfiguration
    Node "localhost"
    {
        File ESETInstaller
        {
            Type = 'Directory'
            DestinationPath = 'C:\ESETInstaller'
            Ensure = "Present"
        }

    }
}

DSCTest
```

I've published this using 
Publish-AzVMDscConfiguration "D:\Test\DSCTest.ps1" -OutputArchivePath "D:\Test\DSCTest.ps1.zip"
and then I uploaded this zip file in Azure BLOB storage.
After that, I tried to apply this configuration to a VM using the following command:

Set-AzVMDscExtension -ResourceGroupName 'TestDSC' -VMName 'TestDSCVM' -ArchiveStorageAccountName 'test***********' -ArchiveResourceGroupName '******' -ConfigurationName $configurationName -ArchiveBlobName "DSCTest.ps1.zip" -ArchiveContainerName 'dsc' -Name "DSCTest" -Version 2.76

In the target machine, I can see that the DSC folder appears

[image]

But on the console I get the error:
[image]

Although, I am able to successfully apply the configuration in the target machine by manually executing the command from inside that VM.

[image]

[image]

Please let me know if anyone has ever faced this issue before. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logs inside the target machine showed that the issue is with the execution policy.

[image]

In my script I changed "Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned" to "Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Scope CurrentUser -Force" and it worked fine.